# javascript why my blob is empty from fetch?

Tags: reactjs, remix, remix.run

Why my blob is empty ?

```
Blob {}
```

code:

MakeBuffer

```
let buffer = [];

[
  {
    buffer: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 ff ff ff ff 0a 39 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 45 78 74 47 53 74 61 74 65 0a 2f 63 61 20 31 0a 3e ... 149398 more bytes>,
    topic: 'RECHNUNG'
  },
  {
    buffer: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 ff ff ff ff 0a 39 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 45 78 74 47 53 74 61 74 65 0a 2f 63 61 20 31 0a 3e ... 144461 more bytes>,
    topic: 'BUCHUNGSBESTÄTIGUNG'
  },
  {
    buffer: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 ff ff ff ff 0a 39 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 45 78 74 47 53 74 61 74 65 0a 2f 63 61 20 31 0a 3e ... 149830 more bytes>,
    topic: 'RECHNUNG'
  },
]

  const dss = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/newPDF', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: buffer
    })
  });

  const res = await dss.blob();

 console.log(res);
```

newPDF

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({request, params}) => {
  const d = await request.json();

  const r = ZipFile(d.data);

    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=ttt.zip", "Content-Length": r.length.toString() });
    return new Response(r, { status: 200, headers });
};
```

I have a similar file with the same content on newPDF but I dont use fetch there but it works, but when I use it with fetch I dont get the download, but when I console log all things it shows the correct data etc. what I am doing wrong with my code ?

Comment: Have you checked whether response headers include "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream". This header should be set by the server sending the blob.